# Trying to read ssm parameter and working fine but write as text and uploading inside my bucket its not happening please find below code

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, aws-ssm

```
import boto3
import os


client = boto3.client('ssm')
s3 = boto3.client("s3")


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    parameter = client.get_parameter(Name='otherparam', WithDecryption=True)
    #print(parameter)
    return parameter ['Parameter']['Value']
    #file = open("/sample.txt", "w")
    #file.write(parameter)
    #file.close
    with open("/tmp/log.txt", "w") as f:
        file.write(parameter)
    
    s3.upload_file("/tmp/log.txt", "copys3toecsbucket-117", "logs.txt")
    #bucket = "copys3toecsbucket-117"
    #file = "/sample.txt"
    #response = s3_client.put_object(Body=file,Bucket='bucket',key='file')
    print(response)
```

trying in aws lambda only.
how to convert ssm parameter into text file which will be trigger file for next step and upload in s3 bucket?

Answer (score 0):

Uploading to bucket is not happening because you are returning a value before the upload happens. When you return a value in the handler, the Lambda function completes.

Removing return will fix it.

```
import boto3
import os


client = boto3.client('ssm')
s3 = boto3.client("s3")


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    parameter = client.get_parameter(Name='otherparam', WithDecryption=True)
    print(parameter)
    
    with open("/tmp/log.txt", "w") as f:
        file.write(parameter)
    
    s3.upload_file("/tmp/log.txt", "copys3toecsbucket-117", "logs.txt")
    
    return True
```

Comment: @Brain thank you for your help it works for me and able to get file in my s3. But now getting different issue while downloading content from s3 not able to see ssm parameter content..any assist..

Comment: Can you ask a new question for that with the new code?

Comment: here is the code the which will push files inside my bucket but not able see any content only blank file

Comment: import boto3
import os


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('ssm')
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    parameter = client.get_parameter(Name='/dev/ec2Instance/tags', WithDecryption=True)
    print(parameter)
    
    file = open("/tmp/log.txt", "w")
    file.write("parameter")
    file.close
    

    s3.upload_file("/tmp/log.txt", "copys3toecsbucket-117", "trigger.txt")
    
 
    return True